# Como juntar valores em comum array php?

Tags: php, array, matriz

Tenho o *array*

```
$vetor[0]['codigo'] = '1';
$vetor[0]['valor']  = '4';

$vetor[1]['codigo'] = '1';
$vetor[1]['valor']  = '2';

$vetor[2]['codigo'] = '2';
$vetor[2]['valor']  = '2';
```

Eu preciso juntar todos os valores com códigos iguais. Fazendo o exemplo acima ficar assim:

O codigo 1 ficar com valor 6

E o codigo 2 ficar com valor 2

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: vc fala somar os valores $vetor[n]['codigo] para ficar apenas um com o total?

Comment: Para juntar todos os valores com codigo igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
$arrayFinal = array();

for($x = 0; $x < count($vetor); $x++){

    $codigo = $vetor[$x]['codigo'];
    if(array_key_exists($codigo, $arrayFinal)){
        $arrayFinal[$codigo]['valor'] += $vetor[$x]['valor'];
        continue;
    }
    $arrayFinal[$codigo] = array("codigo" => $codigo, "valor" => $vetor[$x]['valor']);
}
print_r($arrayFinal);
```

Desta forma ele irá somar apenas os elementos que tem o mesmo código.

Comment: Estava usando o codigo mas deu um problema, o $vetor ele é uma matriz. E esta ele esta somando os valores de arrays diferentes. Por exemplo. https://notepad.pw/arrayexemplo . No terceiro array O valor do 5405 vProd esta retornando 1103.53 Mas o valor correto é 355.00. Tem algo na hora de dar += que esta misturando os arrays

Comment: @PauloRoberto o código é o CFOP é isso? E o valor é vProd certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo CFOP e vProd

Comment: Consegui resolver, coloquei um unset no final do for e ja deu certo Vlw

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu @PauloRoberto ! Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Não tive tempo de testar, mas se seguir a lógica, deve funcionar.

```
    $resultado = [];
        for(i =0; i<sizeof($vetor); i++){
            $resultado[$vetor[i]] = $resultado[$vetor[i]] + $vetor[i]['valor'];
        }
```

Nesse código a posição do vetor resultado vai ser o id

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' in

Comment: Nao estou achando o erro no codigo

Comment: Acho que é só o ponto e virgula depois da linha

Comment: $resultado[$vetor[i]] = $resultado[$vetor[i]] + $vetor[i]['valor'];

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$codigo=$valor=0;
for ($i=0; $i < count($vetor); $i++) { 
    $codigo+=$vetor[$i]['codigo'];
    $valor+=$vetor[$i]['valor'];
}
unset($vetor);//para eliminar o array vetor anterior
$vetor['codigo']=$codigo;
$vetor['valor']=$valor;
print_r($vetor);
```

Comment: Assim ele soma todo o vetor em um só array. Preciso que junte os valores de tudo que tem codigo igual. Para nao criar codigos duplicados.

Comment: Para que o resultado do exemplo seja dois codigos o codigo 1 e o 2 mas o valor do codigo 1 será 6 enquanto do codigo 2 será 2

Comment: entendi, vou arrumar

Comment: segue sempre esse padrão ne?

Comment: Sempre vai ter um codigo e um valor, mesmo padrão pode aparecer codigos novos mas vai continuar a mesma estrutura

Comment: vc quem monta essa estrutura?

Comment: A estrutura sim, porem o conteudo dos codigo e tudo mais vem de um xml